# Net::HTTP -- end of file reached

Tags: ruby

I'm testing my APIs and sometimes the testing scripts fails with error - end of file reached which is related to Net::HTTP. What does this error mean? Why is it happening?

Comment: also generally this problem happens because of redirects which your code may not be handling.

Comment: Does this happen in normal execution of the script ? or only in debug mode ?

Comment: It happens in a testing rake script in production like environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely is due to the connection to the server breaking down. (A socket is considered as a file in UNIX systems). For instance, your test could take too long at a certain moment and the server automatically would close the connection.